# cycle between color throught press of a button

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

hello i am making a xamarin and wpf application but unfortunately i don't know how do i circulate between different colours on a button press, is it possible with enumerais ? and how do i block a button by c# code?

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        string[] colour = {"blue","red","yellow"};
    }

    private void buttonColor_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> circulate between different colours on a button press

```cs
    private Brush[] colors = {Brushes.Blue, Brushes.Red, Brushes.Yellow};
    private int index = 0;
    private void buttonColor_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button button = (Button) sender;
        index++;
        index %= colors.Length;
        button.Background = colors[index];
    }
```

> how do i block a button by c# code?

To disable any WPF element, set its IsEnabled property to false.

Answer (score 0):

You can get colors either from `System.Drawing.Color` or `System.Windows.Media.Colors` in the case of WPF.
Put the colors in an array like so:

```
Color[] color{Color.blue,Color.red,Color.yellow};
```

In your button color call, you can increment the array index by 1 on each call and use the remainder operator  `%` to loop around once the index reaches the end of your array:

```
private void buttonColor_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   index++;
   ElementYouWantToColour.Color = color[index % 3];
}
```

For this to work, you need to also declare a variable for the index:

```
int index = 0;
```

You can replace the number 3 in the example above with the number of elements in your array of colors.